# How to replace While loop by CROSS JOIN?

Tags: sql, t-sql, while-loop, sql-server-2008-r2, cross-join

As I have heard WHILE loop can be replaced by CROSS JOIN to optimize a query, but I have no idea how to do this.
Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need more examples. And you probably mean CROSS APPLY anyway. See https://www.google.com.mt/?ion=1&espv=2#q=cross%20apply%20replacing%20cursor

Answer (score 0):

Example : If you want to produce numbers from 1 to 10000, use

```
select top 10000 row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as number from 
sys.objects as t1 cross join sys.objects as t2
```